# Flip mapView when button Pressed in iphone?

Tags: iphone, transform, flip, mkmapview

I have a mapview, and i want to display another view with flip of mapview like tabbarcontrollers flip when button pressed. Button is placed below the mapview(this occupies only 80% remaining 20%button), then how to flip only mapview without flipping the button.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following method for this. If you find any difficulty please let me know.

1. Define a UIView flipContainerView that will contain either mapView or anotherView
2. Add mapView to flipContainerView (and not anotherView) and flipContainerView to self.view
3. set frames of flipContainerView, mapView and anotherView appropriately. mapView and anotherView will have same frame.
4. Call following method to flip between mapView and anotherView

```
    -(void) MapOranotherView
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:flipContainerView cache:YES];
        if ([mapView superview])
        {

            [mapView removeFromSuperview];
            [flipContainerView addSubview:anotherView];
            [flipContainerView sendSubviewToBack:anotherView];
        }
        else
        {

            [anotherView removeFromSuperview];
            [flipContainerView addSubview:mapView];
            [flipContainerView sendSubviewToBack:mapView];
        }
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```